# Mapping in Batch. Are relative Coordinates possible?

Tags: batch-file

I got pretty good at programming in batch. I know its not made for games but i try. I even got that far that i could create a map where things happen. Problem is, i have to specify each and every block. I need relative coordinates.
Here is an example of my Mapping.

```
set a1=O
set a2=O
set a3=O
set a4=O

set b1=O
set b2=O
set b3=O
set b4=O

set c1=O
set c2=O
set c3=O
set c4=O

:mapping
echo %a1%%a2%%a3%%a4%
echo %b1%%b2%%b3%%b4%
echo %c1%%c2%%c3%%c4%
```

This will result in:

```
OOOO
OOOO
OOOO
```

With this i can create Maps. So for a block to change i have to do "set a2=X"
resulting in

```
OXOO
OOOO
OOOO
```

But when creating large games it gets very intense when trying to map.
Is there any way i could get relative coordinates to work?
I was able to create Flappy Bird with this! Here is a Pastebin link to the code of it: http://pastebin.com/h34xdSd8
You can look at it and try it out if you want.(If you do so then exclude the line "if %run% neq true exit", change .exe in line 227 to .bat and create a file named Keyboard.bat with this code: http://pastebin.com/J3EkMR4q.) Its hand written too.
and with that code you can see how hard it is..
Please help, i need relative coordiantes.

**Edit:**
    `for %%a in (a b c d e f g) do for /L %%i in (1,1,21) do set %%a%%i=0`

This Code worked for me. It will Setup all my Blocks.

One more Problem though. Is there any easy way to use this to move objects? Like when pressing left that my Characted moves one block to the left without me having to specify that block, so relative.

Comment: Without following any link, there are `For` loops and there are substrings. So to initialize you could use `For %%y in (a b c d) Do For /l %%x in (1,1,4) Do Set %%y%%x=0`. But I'd use one var for the x-axis and a pseudo array for the y-axis

Comment: What you need is learn about the `for` command! In your pastebin listing, the initialization that you perform in lines 58-210 could be done in a single line this way: `for %%a in (a b c d e f g) do for /L %%i in (1,1,21) do set %%a%%i=0`

Comment: OMG thx so much! Now i dont have to setup them up so bad. One more question though, in flappy birds when im moving the pipes, im talking to each block, is there any way to make this easy too?

Comment: Btw when doing "for /L %%i in (1,1,21)" waht does the 1,1,21 do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

for coordinates you can try:

```
set /a x=12
set /a y=12
set "q_%x%_%y%=X"
```

this sets `q_12_12` to `X`.
You can use `for` for the definition and `echo`ing of the variables (try `for /?` for help with `for`).